# InnoDB lock read until write complete

Tags: java, mysql, innodb

I have 2 servers (two connections), the problem is that when server A writes a directory and a user in server B requests the directory at the same time he gets the old result, not the new one. What is a convenient way to fix this?

```
private synchronized String readDirectory(String entry, Path directory) {
  String selectSql = "SELECT directory FROM entries WHERE path = ?";
  try (PreparedStatement selectStatement = connection.prepareStatement(selectSql)) {
    selectStatement.setString(1, entry);
    try (ResultSet rs = selectStatement.executeQuery()) {
      if (rs.next()) {
        return PathUtils.parseDigest(rs.getString("directory"));
      }
    }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
  return NO_DIRECTORY;
}

private synchronized void writeDirectory(String entry, Path directory) {
  String pathString = PathUtils.toString(directory);
  String insertSql = "INSERT or REPLACE INTO entries (path, directory) VALUES (?,?)";
  try (PreparedStatement insertStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertSql)) {
    insertStatement.setString(1, entry);
    insertStatement.setString(2, pathString);
    insertStatement.executeUpdate();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is "directory" something in the filesystem?  Or the name of a database table?  Check out `GET_LOCK("directoryname")`

Answer (score 0):

My simple explain for you: The keyword `synchronized` is only work in the same java application process. If multi java application processes request the shared database, you can use distributed lock to avoid to update concurrently. Or you can use database share/exclusive lock: `lock in share mode` or `for update`. e.g: SELECT directory FROM entries WHERE path = ? for update;